# No button to accept/deny edits?

Tags: support

I just got an edit on one of my posts.

However, where is the button to accept/deny the edit!?? Instead, I manually added the edit into my post because I could not find any way to accept his edit.

Maybe I am just being stupid.... But I just cannot see it anywhere!

Post:
[How can I increment a number in a file by an amount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629084/how-can-i-increment-a-number-in-a-file-by-an-amount)

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @Sam Since I could not accept or deny the edit, I edited my own post with the same edits he gave.
If I could have accepted the edit, then I would have been more than happy to give him credit for his edit.
Also, this was on my own post. Surely I should be able to accept an edit on MY OWN POST, no matter how much rep I have?

Comment: Can you add a link to the post in question please.

Comment: Hmmm, the revision history shows that every edit was made by you. Normally, you would receive a notification when an edit has already been applied to your post, so I'm not sure what's happening here. Maybe explain exactly what happened?

Comment: An edit was definitley suggested - http://gyazo.com/f18fa1606864b9ba1594fdd7e75504ff - however, for whatever reason, I had no button to accept or deny said edit.

Comment: @Joehot200 Please post a link to the actual suggested edit, not just a picture of your notification.

Comment: Rejected by the time you saw it, but users with your rep don't get to see the review stats? - just a guess. It's a pretty terrible suggested edit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5245884

Comment: @Sam That's just not true.  The author of a post has a binding vote on suggested edits.

Comment: @Servy Oh right, I've never seen any docs say so, can I have a link?

Comment: @Sam Just read the FAQ... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work

Comment: @Servy No wonder why I didn't see it, I was searching MSO, not MSE. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accept the edit yourself *if the edit had not already been acted on*.  But it had been.  It had been rejected.  If the edit hadn't been rejected when you saw it, *then* you could have approved it.

Comment: So it had been rejected?

Comment: @Joehot200 Yes.  That's why I said, "It had been rejected."

Comment: Could you just point out to me where on the edit it says it is rejected?

Thanks.

Comment: @Joehot200 http://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw43r.png

Comment: Ah! My AdBlock had detected that part of the page as an ad and so did now show it. I whitelisted it and now see it :).

Thanks for making me realize something was different!